# Drag Links to Folders Toolbars on the Taskbar

Tags: windows, links, drag-and-drop

I often have the need to drag a URL-link from my browser to a folder that is shared via a cloud backup service. That way I have those links available to me at work or vis–à–vis. (This method works best in my working environments.)

While I managed in various ways to accomplish this, I have always wished that I could just drag a link, as I do files, to a folder toolbar (Right-click the taskbar, select "Toolbars", and then select "New toolbar") on the taskbar and quickly be done with it--"Set it and forget it."

I need a way to quickly and easily drag and drop links to a folder on the taksbar.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Windows 7. Not tested with 8 or 10.

With a little trick one can drag and drop not only files into a folder toolbar, but also links from a browser as well.

The trick is to drag the link to the double greater-than arrow (arrow) of the targeted folder toolbar, release the left mouse button as the mouse cursor hovers over the arrow, and then quickly click the arrow. Voilà! A copy of the link is now in the target folder.

One caveat: If there are other folders in the target folder toolbar, Windows will try to put the link into one of them instead of the target folder. The trick is to drag the link over the folder toolbar from the left to the right, and then release it just as the cursor switches from the "can't put that here" lined-circle warning icon."

With practice, it becomes second nature.

Enjoy.